# JTextArea with JScrollPane isn't scrolling once full

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, textarea, scrollable

I'm trying to make my JTextArea scrollable when it fills up with text but when I add a JScrollPane it just adds a scrollbar that doesn't do anything. When I add more text than my JTextArea can display it doesn't change and doesn't append any more text.

```
    Container window = getContentPane();
    window.setLayout(new FlowLayout());

    display = new JTextArea(TEXT_AREA_ROWS, TEXT_AREA_COLUMNS);
    display.setLineWrap(true);
    display.setPreferredSize(TEXT_AREA_DIMENSIONS);
    display.setBackground(TEXT_BG_COLOR);
    display.setForeground(TEXT_COLOR);
    display.setEditable(false);
    display.setFont(TEXT_FONT);
    window.add(display);

    scroll = new JScrollPane(display);
    scroll.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(JScrollPane.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_AS_NEEDED);
    scroll.setPreferredSize(display.getPreferredSize());
    window.add(scroll);
```

Thanks in Advance

EDIT: Realised my mistake, I was setting the preferred size of the textArea instead of the scrollPane.
This is solved by removing `display.setPreferredSize(TEXT_AREA_DIMENSIONS);` and adding a `scroll.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(width, height));` Silly me.

Comment: Don't use setPreferredSize() on the scroll pane either. There is no need to do this. You created the JTextArea by specifying the rows/column. That will be the preferred size of the text area.

Comment: @camickr thank you, that works too. It does have the strange affect of not scrolling with the text ie the text you type is offscreen and you need to scroll to see it

Comment: works fine for me. See the [Text Sampler Demo](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/text.html).

Comment: @camickr It does work, but if you append text to it with display.append(string) then the text gets added to the bottom which may or not be on screen at the time. In my code it automatically scrolls with the text, ie what you append to the area is always on screen

Answer (score 0):

> but if you append text to it with display.append(string) then the text gets added to the bottom which may or not be on screen at the time.

Well, you didn't state that you were using the append(...) method in your original question. That is why you should always post a proper [SSCCE](http://www.sscce.org/) that demonstrates the problem so we don't have to guess what you are doing.

See [Text Area Scrolling](http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2008/10/22/text-area-scrolling/) for the probable problem and a solution.